Projecting Natural Earth Data to ESRI:102012

I'm a complete novice and experiencing an issue while reprojecting Natural Earth data from EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 to ESRI:102012. As seen in the attached image, the output is distorted and misaligned. I've tried several methods, including reprojecting individual layers and avoiding any intermediate steps, but I continue to encounter this problem.
How can I correctly reproject this data?

It looks like you have polygons crossing a discontinuity, you will need to break those before reprojecting

102012 is Esri-defined rather than EPSG-defined. It uses Lambert conformal conic. The central meridian is +105, so you need clip and/or close polygons that cross the -75 longitude line.
